# Ошибка yolo python

Tags: python, opencv

При запуске тестового кода появляется ошибка.

Что с ней делать?

Код:

```
import cv2
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
import numpy as np
import time

option = {
    'model': 'C:/Users/Andrey/Downloads/darkflow-master/cfg/yolo.cfg',
    'load': 'C:/Users/Andrey/Downloads/darkflow-master/bin/yolo.weights',
    'threshold': 0.15
}

tfnet = TFNet(option)

capture = cv2.VideoCapture('videofile_1080_20fps.avi')
colors = [tuple(255 * np.random.rand(3)) for i in range(5)]

while (capture.isOpened()):
    stime = time.time()
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    results = tfnet.return_predict(frame)
    if ret:
        for color, result in zip(colors, results):
            tl = (result['topleft']['x'], result['topleft']['y'])
            br = (result['bottomright']['x'], result['bottomright']['y'])
            label = result['label']
            frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, tl, br, color, 7)
            frame = cv2.putText(frame, label, tl, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        print('FPS {:.1f}'.format(1 / (time.time() - stime)))
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Andrey>python C:\Users\Andrey\Downloads\darkflow-master\new.py
C:\Users\Andrey\Downloads\darkflow-master\darkflow\dark\darknet.py:54: UserWarning: ./cfg/yolo.cfg not found, use C:/Users/Andrey/Downloads/darkflow-master/cfg/yolo.cfg instead
  cfg_path, FLAGS.model))
Parsing C:/Users/Andrey/Downloads/darkflow-master/cfg/yolo.cfg
Loading C:/Users/Andrey/Downloads/darkflow-master/bin/yolo.weights ...
Successfully identified 203934260 bytes
Finished in 0.02900528907775879s
Model has a coco model name, loading coco labels.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrey\Downloads\darkflow-master\new.py", line 12, in <module>
    tfnet = TFNet(option)
  File "C:\Users\Andrey\Downloads\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\build.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.framework = create_framework(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Andrey\Downloads\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\framework.py", line 59, in create_framework
    return this(meta, FLAGS)
  File "C:\Users\Andrey\Downloads\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\framework.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.constructor(meta, FLAGS)
  File "C:\Users\Andrey\Downloads\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\yolo\__init__.py", line 20, in constructor
    misc.labels(meta, FLAGS) #We're not loading from a .pb so we do need to load the labels
  File "C:\Users\Andrey\Downloads\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\yolo\misc.py", line 36, in labels
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './cfg/coco.names'
```

Comment: Покапавшись 43 минуты, я понял в чём проблема. Нужно зайти: C:\Users\VashUser\Downloads\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\yolo и найти там файл "misc.py", после чего строку "file" изменить на "file = 'C:/Users/VashUser/Downloads/darkflow-master/cfg/coco.names'" Если у кого-то тож самое будет - надеюсь помог

Answer (score 1):

don't change the 'misc.py' if you look at the 'misc.py' then you'll see that 'file = os.path.join(FLAGS.config, coco_names)' it tries to join the filename with wathever you put in 'config'

so if you add a config like:

```
tfnet = TFNet({
    "model": "/home/willem/projects/darkflow/cfg/yolo.cfg", 
    "load": "/home/willem/projects/darkflow/bin/yolo.weights",
    "config": "/home/willem/projects/darkflow/cfg",
    "threshold": 0.1,
    "gpu": 0.3
})
```

it will be fixed

Comment: Our working language is Russian therefore please translate your answere into Russian.

Answer (score 0):

Покапавшись 43 минуты, я понял в чём проблема. Нужно зайти:

`C:\Users\VashUser\Downloads\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\yolo`

и найти там файл "`misc.py`", после чего строку "`file`" изменить на "`file = 'C:/Users/VashUser/Downloads/darkflow-master/cfg/coco.names'`"`

Если у кого-то тож самое будет - надеюсь помог